# Passing value between activity to fragment on android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

**On Activity:**

```
@Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 // on tab selected
 // show respected fragment view
  Log.v("Test", "Menjalankan intent antar activity ke fragment");
  Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
  //String message= "From activity";
  int nilai=10;
  bundle.putInt("Nilai", nilai);
  Log.v("Testing", "Data yang akan dikirim "+nilai);
    //set Fragmentclass Arguments
  Lirik f=new Lirik();
  f.setArguments(bundle);

  viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
 }
```

**Fragment code:**

```
package com.example.egmim;

import com.example.support.dbAdapter;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class Lirik extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lirik_view, container, false);

        Log.v("Testing", "Menjalankan proses pengambilan data dari activity");

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
          if (bundle != null) {
              Log.v("Testing", "Data adalah ");
          }else{
              Log.v("Testing", "Data null");
          }



        //searchonDB();
        return rootView;
    }





}
```

When compiler said: null exception on line 25. (java.lang.nullexception)
and the line 25 is

```
  int strtext=getArguments().getInt("Nilai", 0);
```

What's wrong?

```
01-10 06:39:53.734: V/Testing(4097): Proses Intent dijalankan, nomor yang dipilih adalah 1

01-10 06:39:54.144: V/Test(4097): Menjalankan intent antar activity ke fragment

01-10 06:39:54.154: V/Testing(4097): Data yang akan dikirim 10

01-10 06:39:54.845: V/Testing(4097): Menjalankan proses pengambilan data dari activity

01-10 06:39:54.875: D/AndroidRuntime(4097): Shutting down VM

01-10 06:39:54.894: W/dalvikvm(4097): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)

01-10 06:39:55.104: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-10 06:39:55.104: E/AndroidRuntime(4097): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-10 06:39:55.104: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at com.example.egmim.Lirik.onCreateView(Lirik.java:24)

01-10 06:39:55.104: E/AndroidRuntime(4097):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
```

Comment: It should be

     `int strtext=getArguments().getInt("nilai", 0);`

Comment: You are passing "nilai" as key but extracting with "Nilai" key thats why.

Comment: Wrong key is being passed, should be "nilai"

Comment: still same after fix it

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything to the `Lirik` fragment you're creating here. The instance `onCreateView()` is run on is likely something else without an arguments bundle, hence `getArguments()` returns null.

Comment: post your full Fragment code.

Comment: `Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
     Log.v("Testing", "Data adalah ");
    }else{
     Log.v("Testing", "Data null");
    }
`
the result is null

how to fix so i can pass value?
@SpringBreaker and @laalto

Comment: try adding `int strtext= bundle .getInt("nilai");' this line.

Comment: take a look my full code of fragment @SpringBreaker

Comment: which log is printing in this case?

Comment: @laalto what's suppose i do?

Answer (score 2):

Your Text is :

```
int strtext=getArguments().getInt("Nilai", 0);
```

It should Be:

```
int strtext=getArguments().getInt("nilai", 0);
```

Edit :

Check Out this Question which is Related to your Problem:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634623/communicating-between-dynamically-created-fragment-giving-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: Thanks but after i fix it the trouble still same

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        int strtext;

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle data = getArguments();
            strtext= data.getInt("Nilai");
          }

    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lirik_view, container, false);
      Log.v("Testing", "Menjalankan proses pengambilan data dari activity");

      Log.v("Testing", "Data adalah "+strtext);
      return rootView;
     }
    }
```

Comment: @user3181552: I am sorry i couldn't get your question ?

Comment: I mean in activity class
whether it is correct the code?

Sorry for my english

Comment: @user3181552: yeah.Its fully correct and gives me correct result.